# Run time error '1004' application or object defined error with getpivot data

Tags: excel, vba

the following getpivotdata call is throwing the above error.  Any thoughts or comments?

```
MsgBox (ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).GetPivotData("Design Review ID", "Review Type", "FDR", "SS Mgr", A12, "Status to Plan", "Late").Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch the a12 cell callout to a variable that had the same value. It appears that excel did not like how I was calling out the range.